# Subversion respository dont update project

Tags: svn

I'm having problems with the update files using subversion. I have a Ubuntu server running a subversion server and a web server. My client is a sublime text2 IDE on a Mac OS. When I commit a file, the repository updates, but not project.

My repository is in /home/svn/repo. My project is on localhost at the same machine.(/var/www).

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the automatic deployment of the project to `/var/www` worked some time ago and now it is not then you should check repository hook scripts in [`/home/svn/repo/hooks`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks). You had the [post-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) which either did `svn export` or `svn update` on `/var/www` (or lower) and it stopped working. Two possible causes here:

- problems with permissions,
- the hook was removed or it's code got broken somehow.